# Import fonts to react project with webpack and styled components

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2, styled-components

I'm trying to import fonts from a local resource in my react project which uses webpack and styled components. I have a fonts folder with the following code:

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';
import { fontWeight } from './vars';

export const fontFaces = css`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OurFont';
    src: url('/resources/fonts/OurFont-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: ${fontWeight.bold};
    font-style: normal;
  }
`;
```

then I have a global styles file with:

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import { fontFaces } from './fonts';

export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  ${fontFaces}
`;
```

In my app component I use the ThemeProvider from styled-components like this (left out some code non relevant code here for brevity):

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{ theme }}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <AppHeader />
      <AppNavigator />       
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}}
```

And the relevant code from webpack:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['babel-loader'],
    },
    {
      test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

I tried following the advice from [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/233) thread but it does not seem to work for me as I get an error in the console which says GET http://localhost:5001/resources/fonts/OurFont-Bold.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or if there is another approach? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this problem by importing the font in your JS and passing it down to your styled components css template tag:

```js
import { css } from 'styled-components';
import { fontWeight } from './vars';

import myFontURL from '../../mypath/fonts/OurFont-Bold.woff2';

export const fontFaces = css`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'OurFont';
    src: url(${myFontURL}) format('woff2');
    font-weight: ${fontWeight.bold};
    font-style: normal;
  }
`;
```

Be sure to not use `/resources/fonts/OurFont-Bold.woff2`, and use a relative path to your current file's directory instead.

Comment: That seems to work :) Quick follow up question: Do you know if this will work for a production build?

Comment: Yes, it definitely should – unless you use some kind of CDN, then you need to configure webpack specifically for that.

Answer (score 3):

Facing the same problem and tried the above stated solution, but it doesn't work and i get the error message: 
`Cannot find module '../fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf'`

I'm using typescript so do I need to add some kind of export to be able to use the import statement for that kind of path?

Edit:
solved by adding `declare module "*.ttf";` to my typings.d.ts file and removing the format("ttf") in `src: url(${fontUrl}) format("ttf");` in @font-face

Comment: Basically TS doesn't deal with CSS.  I solved by just adding a directory copy to my TS build command

Comment: In my case, the trick was to remove the format("ttf").

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem creating a file `falename.css`(in my case was `font.css`) and the `@font-face` how is below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'inter-black';
    src: url('../assets/font/Inter-Black.ttf');
    font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'inter-light';
    src: url('../assets/font/Inter-Light.ttf');
    font-display: swap;
}
```

then you will import it into the your project `index.js`
[importation print of `font.css`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfX4p.png)

After this you can use the code in styled-component

```
export const MainTitle = styled.h1`
    font-family: 'inter-black';
`;
```